# How to properly position block elements vertically and horizontally?

Tags: css, layout, css-float, positioning

What I'd like to accomplish is to have an `h1` in the left bottom corner and a `ul` in the right bottom corner. [image]

I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RubenGeert/362Pd/embedded/result/) for it that isn't quite right yet.

The easiest way seems using `position:absolute;` on both elements and perhaps I'll eventually go with that. However, I think you're not supposed to position anything absolutely unless there's no better options.

An obvious alternative seems using `float:left;` and `float:right;` but in this case the `ul` will sit too high. Perhaps I can "push it down" by adding `margin-top` but I'll have to figure out exactly how much in that case. Doesn't seem elegant at all.

A third alternative could be using `display:inline-block` but this doesn't even get the horizontal alignment right.

Option four seems tinkering around with `position:relative` but again I'll have to figure out exactly how much the position needs to be adjusted in this case.

I must be overlooking something obvious but is there a better option here than absolute positioning?

Comment: Chances are you're going to use either `position:absolute` or `float`. In this case, `float` will suffice without you having to use margins, you just need to make use of `line-height` where necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution that may work for you:

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/362Pd/1/)**

In this demo I used the `float:left` and `float:right` solution. Mostly because you were already pushing the `h1` element down with padding. I gave both a `float` and used `margin` instead of padding to position them lower.

CSS:

```
h1{
  float: left;
  margin:.5em 0em 0em 1em;
  font:bold 2em arial;
}

ul{
  float: right;
  list-style:none;
  margin: 1.5em 0em .5em;
} 

header{
 //existing styles here
 height: 55px;  // <- needed since the other elements are now floated
}
```